# Implementing Error from Back End to Front End

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I creating a MERN stack application, on the back end I have errorHandling, and create a backend code for register user. All goes well, however some custom error handling didn't display if I made some test. If user already existed in the database it display the  `Error: Request failed with status code 500` which it should be the `throw new Error('User already exists');` from the back end error. Using this line of code works `return res.status(400).json({ message: "User already exists" });` it works, but I have files that handle error, so that I can throw an error. Suggestion is highly appreciated since I'm still learning backend code.

```js
export const errorResponserHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 400;
  res.status(statusCode).json({
    message: err.message,
    stack: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? null : err.stack,
  });
};
```

Below is the code for backend:

```js
const registerUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    // Check if user already exists or not
    let user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user) {
      throw new Error('User already exists');
    }
    // Creating a new user
    user = await User.create({ name, email, password });
    return res.status(201).json({
      _id: user._id,
      avatar: user.avatar,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      verified: user.verified,
      admin: user.admin,
      token: await user.getJWTToken(),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

And the frontend code:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const signup = async ({ name, email, password }) => {
   try {
      const { data } = await axios.post("/api/users/register", {
         name,
         email,
         password,
      });
      return data;
   } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.data.message)
         throw new Error(error.response.data.message);
      throw new Error(error.message);
   }
};
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import MainLayout from '../../components/MainLayout';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useMutation } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { signup } from '../../services/index/users';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';
import './register.css';

const Register = () => {
  //creating a mutation for registering a users
  const { mutate, isLoading } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: ({ name, email, password }) => {
      return signup({ name, email, password });
    },

    //after getting the data from the mutation this function run
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      toast.error(error.message);
      console.log(error);
    },
  });
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
    watch,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      confirmPassword: '',
    },
    mode: 'onChange',
  });

  //getting the data from the form
  const submitHandler = (data) => {
    const { name, email, password } = data;
    mutate({
      name,
      email,
      password,
    });
  };

  //monitor the input from the password input
  const password = watch('password');

  return ( from here the code for the form );
};

export default Register;
```

Comment: I don't see the backend code that registers your error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Your `errorResponserHandler` middleware looks good to me and also your route for sign up a user because you throw an error in your async function, catch the error and send the error via the `next` function to your `errorResponserHandler` middleware.

What we don't see in your example is where you add your middleware to your express server?
If you still get the default express error handling (what you mention in your question with the status code 500), it means you did not add your middleware or you added it to early to your express server. Because of that express will send the thrown error directly as response without processing the error with your error middleware.
The error middleware has to be the last one you add and it has to be added after your route definitions.

This backend code solution helps you to catch all thrown errors in your route functions and manage them in your `errorResponserHandler`

```
// this is an example index.js code snippet for starting an expressjs server and add your routes and error middleware.

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// define your error middleware
const errorResponserHandler = async (err, req, res, next) => {...};

// register user route
app.post("/sign-up", registerUser);
// other routes...

// add your error middleware below all your route definitions and as last middleware 
app.use(errorResponserHandler);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```